# Using Regex with netstat (Windows)

Tags: regex, windows, findstr, netstat

I am trying to get a single command line to display both TCP listening and established states and UDP connections.

So this would be one command line to show the following:

```
netstat -abfn  | findstr /r "[0-9]*[ED|ING]$"
netstat -abfn  | findstr UDP
```

I tried the below command line but am not able to sanitize the *

```
netstat -abfn  | findstr /r "[0-9]*[ED|ING|*:*]$"
```

Can anyone please post and explain the successful regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you need is:

```
netstat -abfn  | findstr /r "TCP.*[ING]$ TCP.*[ED]$ UDP.*$"
```

That's because the `findstr` has limited use of regex's and doesn't support the `|` (**OR**) operator, but you can pass to it multiple patterns. In your case one for each:

- TCP LISTENING `TCP.*[ING]$`
- TCP ESTABLISHED `TCP.*[ED]$`
- UDP `UDP.*$`

Also, this regex is not case sensitive to make it so you must use the `/i` parameter, if you like.